# Redirect network traffic to certain connection

Tags: 8.1-update-1, networking

Is it possible I can control my certain apps to use my own data plan even I have an active WIFI connection?

The reason I ask the question is that I use my phone to hook up my company's exchange server to read emails, I have to use company's internal WIFI network to establish the connection. But meanwhile I don't like to use my company's network to listen to online music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible. All apps will always choose Wifi when availiable. Consider adding a request on http://windowsphone.uservoice.com

Comment: Great, I have posted my suggestion over there.